# Hibernation and suspending on the Cinnamon desktop

Tags: suspend, hibernate, cinnamon

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Then I decided to install the desktop Cinnamon.

But I noticed that it can't manage the Hibernation and the suspending of the session.
It is not enable to hibernate the session, to suspend it also.
Please What can be the reason?

Comment: Hi hackthatos and welcome to Askubuntu! I have a couple of questions for you: Does hibernation and suspend work when using the Unity desktop? And when you are using the Cinnamon desktop, can you suspend your computer by running `sudo pm-suspend`; or `sudo pm-hibernate` to hibernate it?

Comment: @user311982, suspending  and Hibernation work correctly on Unity Desktop. When I use `pm-suspend`, it works, but `pm-hibernate` can't; it stops but  can't restore. I've installed Tuxoncle for the hiberantion.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Tuxonice, so I cannot offer help with that :( Have you ever used Ubuntu's default hibernation method (using swsusp)?

Answer (score 2):

it's easy to fix. Insert:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

into

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

and remove tuxonice

Comment: You might run killall indicator-session-service or logoff and logon, but it worked out of the box to me